# Getting JSON Error in Wordpress with Created Roles

Tags: json, wordpress, roles

I am getting a JSON error: Datatables warning.... Invalid JSON response, with created roles in Wordpress. I have tried 2 different role creating plugins, PublishPress' Capability Manager Enhanced as well as Members. I am cloning the Subscriber role. The only need for additional roles is to limit access to certain pages through menu access.

When accessing the page with the error with either Admin or Subscriber role accounts, there isn't the error and everything loads correctly. When I change to the created role or add the created role in addition to the Subscriber role (a Members feature), the error appears. I have tried ensuring the SSL allows for secured and unsecured, enabling and disabling all the capabilities, etc., and nothing has fixed the error.

I have searched google and this site and haven't seen a solution. If I missed it, please kindly direct me to the post.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the conflicting setting in another plugin. Most likely very isolated to my set up, but just in case someone else has a similar issue... Using a plugin: "Role Based Redirect" when "Restrict Dashboard Access" is checked for a role, it causes the error I described above.